# Htaccess doesn't redirect folders

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website and I want the redirect all files to index.php file. But I have problem with folders. domain.com/panel/ doesnt work. but domain.com/panel/index.php works.

in localhost with wampserver, works good. But in hosting doesnt work.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Site yönlendirme motoru
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*?\.(?:html?|php))$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Not: I want only html and php files because, if i dont do this, images, css, js files doesnt work. Is there any another way? How can i redirect all files to index.php while images, css, js files still works?

Not 2: I want panel folder to redirect because of security. like this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$url_array = explode('/', $url);
if($url_array[0] == 'panel') {
if($url_array[1] != 'login.php' and (!isset($_SESSION['user']))){
header('Location: login.php');
die();
}
include($url);
}
```

edit:
What i have to make for except to images, css, js files on htaccess?

Comment: You certainly can route _all_ requests through a routing script (index.php). You just need to deliver the respective file content when requested and you need to take care to send the correct http headers, indicating if the sent content is css or javascript. Otherwise the browser cannot make sense if the content.

Comment: About the folder issue: could it be that the folders you try to redirect actually exist in the physical file system? That would explain the behavior your describe, since you explicitly implemented a condition to only rewrite if the folder does _not_ exist.

Comment: @arkascha thanks for your answer sir. how can i send correct http headers? and how many file extension need http header? png, jpg, gif, jpeg, bmp, zip, pdf?

Comment: Every response a http server sends need to have some http headers and all _should_ have a content type defined. Often the http server can "guess" the correct one and fill it in, for example if a physical file is delivered. But that does not work if you route requests, since then you simply send out payload and the http server itself does _not_ add a content type header. You should do that yourself for _all_ files you deliver like that.

Comment: thanks @arkascha . can you give me an example? if(is png) {png header} like this?

Comment: You will find endless examples for that on the internet. But more important is: start reading the documentation of the tools you use, here the `header` function php offers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php. About your specific example of a png image: that would be `header("Content-type: image/png");`. And once you are add it you can also help the browser and add a content length ;-)

Comment: thanks for help, is there a way for redirect without images on htaccess? @arkascha

Comment: I assume you mean by that to redirect everything _except_ images, right? That is possible, but not that easy, since at the time of the request it is unknown to the http server whether a request will result in an image or something else being the response to the request. You can do that if you route all requests as discussed before and then, inside your php code, decide to redirect or rewrite requests to what you consider an image. If you want to rewrite on http server level you should either have a folder or a naming pattern you add as another `RewriteCond` for _not_ to be rewritten.